# Install a package and all its dependencies without a confirmation prompt with FreeBSD pkg

Tags: freebsd, package-management

Is there a way to automatically install packages and their dependencies, like with `apt-get -y` in Debian, without being prompted each and every time?

Installing Webmin, NGiNX and nano in 1 step, all their dependancies automatically:

```
sudo apt-get -y install webmin nginx nano
```

On FreeBSD 10, *(I'm still getting used to Ports)* I would type:

```
pkg install webmin nginx nano
```

If I append the `-y` switch, it just fails. I looked at the documentation at [meBSD](https://mebsd.com/make-build-your-freebsd-word/pkgng-first-look-at-freebsds-new-package-manager.html) and [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html) and there doesn't seem to be an option/switch to use. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Don't get ports and packages confused. You're trying to install a package but said you're still getting used to ports. I only use ports so I can't help you with the new pkg system.

Comment: Ports is the source code that you then compile yourself and install, whereas `pkg` installs already compiled binaries. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Did you try `pkg install -y webmin nginx nano` ?

Comment: That worked! I was putting the -y switch in the wrong place by using `pkg -y install webmin nginx nano` .... I can't believe I was unable to think outside the box just a little! Is that somewhere in the documentation and I missed it?

Comment: I've wrote it into my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
pkg install -y webmin nginx nano
```

Check `man pkg-install`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> pkg install [-AfgIinFqRUxy] [-r reponame] pkg-origin ...
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  -y  Assume yes when asked for confirmation before package installation.
> ```

Note the **y** in *[-AfgIinFqRUxy]*!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use `yes` command.

```
yes | pkg install webmin nginx nano
```